# Assess the presence of a document in Firestore from a Firebase db rule?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Both in *Firestore security rules* and *Firebase realtime db rules* it is possible to make assessments on a pre-existing document in a specific location:

Firestore example : `get(/databases/$(database)/collection/mydoc).data`

Firebase example : `root.child('collection').child('mydoc').val()`

My question is:
is it possible to cross reference these rules from Firestore to Realtime db? i.e. validate the presence of a Firestore document from a Firebase rule and/or vice versa, possibly avoiding cloud functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to cross reference these (security) rules from Firestore to
> Realtime db?

No, it is not possible to "cross-reference" the different Security Rules between services.

Note that it is the same with Cloud Storage and Firestore or Cloud Storage and the RTDB.

---

As you said you may use a Cloud Function for that and there are several approaches here:

1. Use a Cloud Function to read and write data to e.g. Firestore, and in the Cloud Function check the existence of the node in the RTDB. Writing to/reading from a DB through a Cloud Function may have some drawbacks, see this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c).
2. Use a Cloud Function to mirror the two database structures, e.g. create a new Firestore doc in the `collection` collection when a new RTDB node is created at the `child('collection').child('mydoc')` location. With this second approach you can still use security rules and the client SDKs when writing to and reading from Firestore.

(same logic apply if you invert the databases in the examples above)